# Can I start a JVM with Eden space so big, it runs to completion without any GC. Assuming I have heap of free mem

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection

If I have plenty of memory to spare, can I start a Java application( says mMven ) to run using Eden space alone until completion without any GC ?

Comment: I would have a read about [LMAX Exchange](https://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but not in Java 8. Java 11 will include Epsilon GC ([JEP 318](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/318)) that does nothing to free memory. With any other GC and with large enough heap there is no need to trigger StopTheWorld garbage collection but it isn't guaranteed that it won't happen.

Comment: No direct contradiction: prior to Java 11 there is no guaranteed way to avoid a full GC, but in practice you can make it extremely unlikely by allocating a very large young gen. In Java 11 it will be possible to guarantee this behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I have done this for real applications in Java 6+. I started with a 24 GB Eden space, tiny survivor and tenured spaces. Later I found 8 GB was more than enough.

It would still GC when there was a bug or error, but not under normal operation.

I believe the options were

-Xmn24g -Xmx26g -XX:SurvivorRatio=100

With the default GC.

The application was optimised to produce less than 1 GB/hour so run for a day with a GC.

Comment: can you share the vm options, I tried xmx=xms=16GB survivor ratio like 100 but still see GC around &lt;5G

Comment: It would be worth sharing the corresponding VM flags indeed.

Comment: hell yeah plus one! I worked at a place where the eden space was 64GB if I am not mistaken, they would heat up one VM during an hour or so, then swap it into production, during the night kill it, heat another one...